# How to verify if geoupdate is installed properly or not

Tags: geoip

I have installed geoupate [using this link](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoipupdate/).How can i check if it is installed properly or not. I ran "geoipupdate" command , it is not showing any output just giving the prompt back.

My instance is running on aws , In the documentation they have asked to open port for dns and https , Which is the source ip i should mention in rules.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `geoipupdate -v` to get verbose output. You can also check that the databases are being downloaded into the expected directory.